# html menu in a php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$mainMenu[0][0] = "index.php?prod=0";
$mainMenu[0][1] = "Product One";
$mainMenu[1][0] = "index.php?prod=1";
$mainMenu[1][1] = "Product Two";
$mainMenu[2][0] = "index.php?prod=2";
$mainMenu[2][1] = "Product One";
```

In the first index I save the url of the link. In the second is the text, that should be displayed. How can I run a loop (and what loop should I run) to print the menu?

Comment: what have you tried, what was the actual problem? doesn't seem too hard - for/foreach loop is probably the weapon of choice...

Answer (score 1):

It's a simpe loop and print statement:

```
foreach ($mainMenu as $entry) {
    list($link, $title) = $entry;
    print <<< HTML
        <a href="$link">$title</a>
HTML;
}
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$menu='';
foreach($mainMenu as $menuItem){
    $menu.='<a href="'.$menuItem[0].'">'.$menuItem[1].'</a>';
}
return $menu;
```

EDIT:
...or use the list() method as @mario suggests.  Both should work.